How to make the PING command display more info in Windows?
In older versions of MS-Windows, the ping command displayed a lot of useful information for IPv6 addresses, like: TTL, ICMP Sequence and bytes received.

But now, the default output of the ping command has been dumbed-down in order to decrease the cognitive burden on Windows' users and this information is not displayed :(

Are there any switches that can restore the display of this more-detailed information ?

please do not post pictures of text ... post the text instead

@jsotola:  Where do you think I can get the text from ? Do you expect me to do OCR ?  I got these screenshots from the Internet by Google search.  I do not have all these Windows versions installed.  I just remember that in the past the pings's output was richer.

you copy the text in the command window  and paste it into your question ... you did not say that the screenshots are not yours
